# Use a YAML template as a task/step/job/stage in classic pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a number of existing build and release pipelines defined using the classic interface, but I'm switching over to using the newer YAML pipelines and templates. Converting the existing classic pipelines to YAML pipelines would be too much work, but I would like to define any new pipelines using YAML pipelines and templates. Would there be a way to still use the newly defined YAML templates from the existing classic pipelines if necessary?

Edit: to clarify, this is not a question about [how to bulk migrate classic pipelines to YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895383/migrating-existing-entire-azure-devops-pipeline-to-yaml-based-pipelines-in-bu), but about using YAML templates in classic pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible. In terms of moving from Classic to YAML the Azure DevOps team works on tool which should help converting this. However, this is not ready yet. I check status of the task and it was moved again to [planned](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1702531).

Description of above mentioned task:

> We'll add a migration tool to help convert your classic build pipelines to YAML. While there is a gesture to generate a snippet of YAML for selected tasks in the classic editor, there has been enough feedback from customers calling for a more complete experience to support this migration.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It doesn't let me access that link, though, and I tried with two different user accounts.

Comment: I have no idea why. I'm not related to MS in any away apart my preference in technology :) So I rather don't have special permission entry there. I copied description to give you a chance to see what is there.

Comment: I found out that that I'm able to open the link (which leads to the ADO Roadmap) using an incognito session. In any case, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the upcoming Sprint 178-Update, we will introduce a new "export to YAML" feature for designer build pipelines. Save your pipeline definition, then find "Export to YAML" on the `...` menu.

The new full export **replaces** the "View as YAML" function found in the build editor. The older function was incomplete as it could only inspect what the web UI knew about the build, which sometimes led to incorrect YAML. The new feature takes into account exactly how the pipeline will be processed and has full fidelity with the designer pipeline.

Currently azure devops service is updated to [Sprint-177](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-177-update).

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can find "View YAML" on the job or task section to simplify the migration process:

[image]