# Is there a way to export release pipleines to YAML in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

Is there any way I can export a **release** pipeline in Azure devops to YAML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, `Azure DevOps` can't export a Release Pipeline to `YAML`.

But individual tasks within stages and jobs can be exported from release pipelines by clicking the `“View YAML”` button at the right upper side of a task.

This features is `On Roadmap` for implementation.

---

Support this feature @ https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/export-entire-azure-devops-buildrelease-pipelines/733456

---

**References**

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/export-a-release-pipeline-as-yaml/918911

[Migrating existing (entire) Azure DevOps pipeline to YAML based pipelines (in bulk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895383/migrating-existing-entire-azure-devops-pipeline-to-yaml-based-pipelines-in-bu)